# Determinant about n-th root of unity.

Tags: determinant

$\omega$ is a n-th root of unity, aka $\omega^n=1$, calculate
$$
D=\left| \begin{matrix}
 1&  \omega ^{-1}&  \omega ^{-2}&  \cdots&  \omega ^{-n+1}\\
 \omega ^{-n+1}&  1&  \omega ^{-1}&  \cdots&  \omega ^{-n+2}\\
 \omega ^{-n+2}&  \omega ^{-n+1}&  1&  \cdots&  \omega ^{-n+3}\\
 \vdots&  \vdots&  \vdots&  &  \vdots\\
 \omega ^{-1}&  \omega ^{-2}&  \omega ^{-3}&  \cdots&  1\\
\end{matrix} \right|.
$$

My work: let $\omega_1,\cdots,\omega_n$ are roots of $x^n=1$, $f\left( x \right) =1+\omega ^{-1}x+\cdots +\omega ^{-n+1}x^{n-1}$,
$$
V=\left| \begin{matrix}
 1&  1&  1&  \cdots&  1\\
 \omega _1&  \omega _2&  \omega _3&  \cdots&  \omega _n\\
 \omega _{1}^{2}&  \omega _{2}^{2}&  \omega _{3}^{2}&  \cdots&  \omega _{3}^{2}\\
 \vdots&  \vdots&  \vdots&  &  \vdots\\
 \omega _{1}^{n-1}&  \omega _{2}^{n-1}&  \omega _{3}^{n-1}&  \cdots&  \omega _{n}^{n-1}\\
\end{matrix} \right|,
$$
then
$$
DV=\left| \begin{matrix}
 f\left( \omega _1 \right)&  f\left( \omega _2 \right)&  f\left( \omega _3 \right)&  \cdots&  f\left( \omega _n \right)\\
 \omega _1f\left( \omega _1 \right)&  \omega _2f\left( \omega _2 \right)&  \omega _3f\left( \omega _3 \right)&  \cdots&  \omega _nf\left( \omega _n \right)\\
 \omega _{1}^{2}f\left( \omega _1 \right)&  \omega _{1}^{2}f\left( \omega _2 \right)&  \omega _{3}^{2}f\left( \omega _3 \right)&  \cdots&  \omega _{n}^{2}f\left( \omega _n \right)\\
 \vdots&  \vdots&  \vdots&  &  \vdots\\
 \omega _{1}^{n-1}f\left( \omega _1 \right)&  \omega _{2}^{n-1}f\left( \omega _2 \right)&  \omega _{3}^{n-1}f\left( \omega _3 \right)&  \cdots&  \omega _{n}^{n-1}f\left( \omega _n \right)\\
\end{matrix} \right|=f\left( \omega _1 \right) f\left( \omega _2 \right) \cdots f\left( \omega _n \right) V.
$$
thus $D=f\left( \omega _1 \right) \cdots f\left( \omega _n \right) $.

My problem: $\omega$ is one of $\omega_1,\cdots,\omega_n$, how can I simplify the result
$$\boxed{D=f\left( \omega _1 \right) \cdots f\left( \omega _n \right) }?$$

Comment: 1) You should set $\omega^{-1}=\alpha$. 2) In this way, you will see more clearly that you have a circulant matrix, whose determinant can be computed using FFT (fast Fourier Transform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you subtract the $ω$-multiple of the first row from the second, and consider that $ω^{-n+1}=ω$, then you get ...

In short, the task is much easier than you are thinking.

Alternatively, consider the product with the all-ones vector and use geometric summation
$$
1+ω^{-1}+…+ω^{-n+1}=\frac{1-ω^{-n}}{1-ω^{-1}}
$$
to establish it as non-trivial kernel vector.